# Oracle DB server using almost all memory during SonarQube 6.7.5 scan

Tags: java, database, oracle, memory, sonarqube

Using Sonar 6.7.5 with a JDBC connection to Oracle 12c.  Driver version is 12.2.0.1.0.  Java JDK 1.8.0_111.

Running `mvn sonar:sonar`, specifying only a small portion of the source code using the appropriate switch, since it is taking sometimes *minutes* to process each *file*, and this is likely due to the database server memory usage being at 96%.  It doesn't help that much of this code is very poorly written (complex legacy code with many contributors and lots of problems).

Where do you recommend I look first?  I tried SQLDeveloper tools to monitor activity, but nothing registered.  The Oracle DB is on a different server from where I am running SonarQube.

This is on a system that from which I can't copy files, but I can transcribe Java memory setting or other data as needed.  Please also advise as to log files I could inspect.

Other data, from the SonarQube Administration page:

Compute Engine JVM State

Maximum memory = 1963MB

Free memory    = 1649MB

System load average = 146.0%  (`top` shows high cpu, but not that high)
Worker count = 1

Should I [turn off some rules](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube) and see if that helps?

Comment: Maybe the SonarQube log file could give your more information on what takes so long.

Comment: If the Oracle server is located on a different machine than SonarCube, then Oracle can **not** use "almost all memory" on the computer running SonarCube. It must be SonarCube that uses "almost all memory" - Are those figures from the Oracle server or the SonarCube server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 6.7, the analysis runner does not have a direct connection to the database, so no tuning on the database will have any effect on the *minutes to process each file* issue whatsoever.

I think it can be expected that the SonarJava scanner struggles to parse complex files, since those files would give a hard time to the symbolic execution engine (which powers e.g null pointer de-reference detection rules). I would advise that you run your analysis jobs on a beefier machine if you can - more CPU, more memory allocated to the Maven runner.

Disabling rules in your quality profile can also help, especially if some of them are not relevant for your code base right now. It might be helpful for your team to adopt a progressive enhancement approach to code quality: start with a subset of high severity, high impact rules, concentrate on fixing the leak (i.e avoid introduction of new bugs) and refactoring existing code to reduce cognitive complexity, and then raise the bar by enabling other rules later on.